# Openshift connecting to a socket using JBoss EAP

Tags: java, sockets, jboss, port, openshift

I'm trying to connect to a socket using JBoss EAP in Openshift. I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) Ping to [address.of.destination:10443] failed: Permission denied: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

I think the reason why is because Openshift blocks access to the port.

Also I'm under these conditions:

- I can't change the port on the destination server, since it's not under my control.
- the connection made to the server is made by the library I'm using, which means, it is writing the address and port by itself, so I cannot change the port on the code of the library because it's compiled code already.

Is there a work-around for this situation?

Comment: I tried accessing various ports from my application and I don't see any regular pattern to decide which ports are accessible and which are not, but 10443 is not, tough luck :( and even if this worked, I believe it is subject to change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to bind to the internal IP with port range between 15000 and 35530 https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port. Also read http://blog-judcon.rhcloud.com/?p=97